# how to print 'space character' with the double defined in c?

Tags: c, printf, space

```
double d,e,f;
```

I have 3 variables and my program needs space character in some lines.I try everything but cant find.

```
d='space character'
```

This is what i need.

if( ...)
in here d,e and f calculates number

```
else{
        o="no";
        w="";
        d= ' ' ;
        e =' ';
        f=' ';
        quest="";

        }


        fprintf(bb,"%-10s%-13s%-13.2lf\t%-13.2lf\t%-13.2lf\t%-3s\n", o, w, d,e,f,quest);    

        printf( "%-10s%-13s%-13.2f\t%-13.2f\t%-13.2f\t%-3s\n\n", o, w, d,e,f,quest );
```

Comment: `32` is the ASCII value for space, it's an exact integer value. If you want a character then use `char` type, and assign it e.g. `' '` for space.

Comment: Can someone please explain me the question O_o. I mean should'nt `d=32` be enough here?

Answer (score 1):

if d value equals to `32` will print space.

```
double d;

if (somecondition)
{
   d=32; 
   printf("%c==%d==%f",(char)d,(int) d,d ); //cast to char while printing
}
```

---

You should not put  `' '`(space) into double.

when ever you want, store `32` into d and use cast.

---

Based on your edit, you can do like this

```
if(...)
{
   //do calculations and print and print statements inside if
  fprintf(bb,"%-10s%-13s%-13.2lf\t%-13.2lf\t%-13.2lf\t%-3s\n", o, w, d,e,f,quest); 
}
else
{
  //modify fprintf and printf statements, do not modify values
  fprintf(bb,"%-10s%-13s%- \t%-13.2lf\t%-13.2lf\t%-3s\n", o, w,   e,f,quest); 
                        //^^ here use space.do not use this     ^^ argument d 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `d` as `char`.

```
 char d;
 ...

 if(......)
    d = ' ';
```

Comment: @acme; I think he meant `' '` by writing `space character`.

Comment: but i must declare d as a double couse it calculates some numbers. Also it needs space character without calculating numbers i need both of them numbers + space character

Comment: @jarlaxle No you must not. The C language allows for more than 3 variables to co-exist in the same program...

Comment: @jarlaxle; Show your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

In the C language, all characters exist as small integers (usually 1 byte large). It never makes any sense to store characters in variables used for floating point calculation.

Instead, built up an output format string in the desired format. The most obvious would be

```
printf("%f %f %f", d, e, f);
```

or alternatively, `sprintf` in case you need the string for other purposes than printing it on the screen.

**EDIT :** if the output of space should depend on the values of the doubles, then you should do like this:

```
signed char ascii_value = ' ';

if ( fabs(my_double - (double)ascii_value) <= epsilon * fabs(my_double) )
{
  print(ascii_value);
}
```

And if you have absolutely no idea what the above means or why I did it, you probably shouldn't be doing floating any point programming, not before [reading this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).